Is one allowed to pray for themselves to die
not promoting self harm
Is one allowed to pray to Gd to take their lives? Possible proof is Choni HaMeagel doing this. Though you can argue that was an extreme circumstance. And a possible disproof would be that you’d be praying to lose the opportunity to do mitzvot and whatnot…

R' Akiva sort of did
